# MPDF EAN13 barcode number at the buttom make it bold

Tags: barcode, mpdf, ean-13

I'm generating barcode using MPDF

using this code

`$bar_type = EAN13`

`$data_waltermart = ex. 2000027317400`

```
<barcode type='".$bar_type."' code='".$data_waltermart[0]['sku_cust']."' class='barcode' size='0.8' height='0.5'></barcode>
```

now I'm trying to make this area **"Bold"**

[image]

I know that the number is automatic generated by the EAN13 MPDF. But is there a way to make this bold even through CSS.

It will be highly appreciate if someone has an idea how to hack this area :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried font-weight='bold' style on the barcode element?

Comment: I tried but nothing happened

Comment: Can you try text=0 attribute. Does the number disappear? If so, you could reposition the same number over the bottom of the barcode using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to alter mPDF barcode text appearance without modifying mPDF code directly.

---

Judging from the output. you create your mPDF object with `c` core-fonts-only mode.

Technically, you could ommit the mode constructor parameter and then substitute hard-coded barcode `ocrb` font for a bold variant or any other font you find more to your liking.

Also see the [chapter of the documentation on Fonts](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html).